# Retrieve average values for the earliest date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm practicing MySQL and I'm trying to solve an exercise. I have data that contains reviews to a hotel. The data contains reviews by different users: one user can have many reviews if they have visited more than once. Each review has its own `id` and then review values from 1 to 5.

The reviews also have dates, and now I would like to count the **average reviews of the first visits** (earliest date). My problem is that the ways I have tried to retrieve the earliest date, don't actually work. By this I mean that I get the same results with and without the `HAVING` and `WHERE` methods. Is there someone that could help me with this? Thanks!

Here is my query (I have tried with the `HAVING` and `WHERE` methods)

```
SELECT AVG(overall_rating), AVG(rooms_rating), AVG(service_rating), AVG(location_rating), AVG(value_rating)
FROM reviews
HAVING MIN(review_date)
#WHERE review_date IN (SELECT MIN(review_date) FROM repatrons_reviews GROUP BY id)
```

Here is an example of the data

```
  user_id  | id  |  rooms_rating  | service_rating  |  location_rating  | value_rating |    date  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 matt21   |  123  |       4        |        5        |         2         |      4       |  2007-08-20
```

Comment: Your data doesn't make much sense. The table is missing something like `id_user`. If you cannot assign the review to user you cannot select "earliest review" for each user. There will be only one earliest review and it doesn't make sense to calculate avg from one record.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it. My data contains user_ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
SELECT ...
FROM reviews
HAVING MIN(review_date)
```

cannot work. Let's say the minimum date in the table is `DATE '2020-01-01'`, then what is `HAVING DATE '2020-01-01'` supposed to mean?

This

```
SELECT ...
FROM reviews
WHERE review_date IN (SELECT MIN(review_date) FROM reviews GROUP BY id);
```

is close, but it's not the minimum date per ID, but the minimum date per user ID you want. And if you replace `id` by `user_id`, then there is still a problem, because what is the first date for one user can be the third date for another.

Here is this query corrected:

```
SELECT
  AVG(overall_rating), AVG(rooms_rating),
  AVG(service_rating), AVG(location_rating), AVG(value_rating)
FROM reviews
WHERE (user_id, review_date) IN 
         (SELECT user_id, MIN(review_date) FROM reviews GROUP BY user_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT AVG(r.overall_rating), AVG(r.rooms_rating), AVG(r.service_rating), AVG(r.location_rating), AVG(r.value_rating)
FROM reviews r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reviews WHERE user_id = r.user_id AND date < r.date)
```